# Parsing multiple xml files to a Single Dateframe in R

Tags: xml, r, for-loop

I have 200 xml files in a folder.I wanted to parse all the xml files in the folder and convert it into a single dataframe for text mining purpose.

For a single xml file - i have the below code to process and working fine:

```
library(XML)
d1 <- "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\file.xml"
doc1 <- xmlParse(d1)
Data <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc1,"//Column1"))[c("Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5","Column6")]
```

Thanks

Comment: You can get all the filenames from a folder/directory with `list.files()`, then use one of they `plyr()` "apply" functions (prbly `ldply()`) to cycle through each file, do the `xmlParse()` & `xmlToDataFrame()` and return the entire result as a data.drame

Comment: I have used the below code, based on your suggestion - is this what you tried to convey: `setwd("E:/xxx/SplitFIles/") files <- list.files() parse_xml <-function(FileName) { doc1 <- xmlParse(FileName) doc <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc1,"//Column1"))[c("Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5","Column6")] } Data <- ldply(files,parse_xml)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code works , as advised by hrbrmstr

```
setwd("E:/xxx/SplitFIles/") 
    files <- list.files() 
    parse_xml <-function(FileName) {
     doc1 <- xmlParse(FileName) 
    doc <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc1,"//Column1"))[c("Column2","Column3","Column‌​4","Column5","Column6")] 
    } 
    Data <- ldply(files,parse_xml)
```