# R merge multiple XML files

Tags: xml, r, merge

I am completely unfamiliar with XML but have 700 XML files for which I have a code to extract the right data and put them in a CSV. I would like to merge the XML files but I do not know which function I have to use. For the extraction I use the XML library.

All XML files are the same in structure.

Can anybody help me out? I couldn't find the answer here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this one would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676706/parsing-multiple-xml-files-to-a-single-dateframe-in-r, othewise having similar problems.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38277640/6549166