# R Build an xml corpus out of multiple XML files

Tags: xml, r, xpath, text-mining, corpus

I am trying to process a corpus of xml files for text mining purposes. Is there a way to import multiple files into one xml object/database that could be worked with XPath later?

Is that a smart thing to do? I found a similar reports that import xml files into other data formats, such as dataframes or tm Corpus objects [Parsing multiple xml files to a Single Dateframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676706/parsing-multiple-xml-files-to-a-single-dateframe-in-r), however keeping them in an XML format should keep them tidy, maintain access to context as annotated corpora can have deep trees and make processing simpler because of the nice query language?

Many thanks for the consultation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this small program called [mergex.exe](https://code.google.com/p/mergex/downloads/detail?name=mergex.exe&can=4&q=) useful. It merges several XML files into a single file at the command line, really intuitive and simple.

Comment: Thanks, this is really great! If it could also use filename as an attribute in there, it would be even better, but it does what is needed! Btw new version is at https://code.google.com/p/mergex/downloads/detail?name=mergex-2.1.exe. Not sure what was updated though.