# >900k XML into R

Tags: r, xml

So I am trying to get over 900k xml?/XBRL?/...? files to merge into a single dataframe for further analysis in R. On top of that I only have had little experience with R.

Of course, I tried [Parsing multiple xml files to a Single Dateframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676706/parsing-multiple-xml-files-to-a-single-dateframe-in-r) and http://rpubs.com/jsmanij/131030 and a combination of those, but I can't get it to work.

The additional challenge is that not every xml file has the same amount of keys and/or values.

Here is a snippet on how one of those files look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<opendata xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.kvk.nl/xb/query/service/2016/1/0/0">
    <ns2:opendataField key="DocumentAdoptionDate" value="2017-11-07"/>
    <ns2:opendataField key="FinancialYear" value="2016"/>
    <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheet">
        <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetBeforeAfterAppropriationResultsTitle">
            <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetBeforeAfterAppropriationResults" value="Na"/>
        </ns2:opendataField>
        <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetTitle">
            <ns2:opendataField key="Assets" value="4407586">
                <ns2:opendataField key="AssetsNoncurrent" value="1381493">
                    <ns2:opendataField key="PropertyPlantEquipment" value="63493"/>
                    <ns2:opendataField key="FinancialAssets" value="1318000"/>
                </ns2:opendataField>
            </ns2:opendataField>
        </ns2:opendataField>
    </ns2:opendataField>
</opendata>
```

I found a Python code https://dirkmjk.nl/2017/kvk/kvk.py, not sure if it works because it was for an older datadump. I am on Windows, but maybe you get the idea of what I want to achieve?

Thanks everyone for helping out this noob beginner....

Comment: The given snippet does not contain valid XML. Could it be easier to merge the files with some other tool? There are some other questions on SO that cover this...

Comment: Thats how beginner I am.... the files all end at .xml, hence I thought these are xml files. But, apparantly, they are XBRL files which are based upon xml? The question remains, though....

Comment: If XBRL files are based on XML, they should contain a valid XML structure. The given snippet is no valid XML, so it cannot be a part of XBRL. On the other hand, if you can merge XML files with some tool and XBRL files are XML files, you can merge XBRL files with the very same tool

Comment: I added the complete beginning of one of those mysterious source files. And rephrased my question.. maybe it is more understandable now?

Comment: Are you sure these files contain dashes in between? And what about the existing tools to merge XML files, do these work?

Comment: thank you for keeping commenting Nico Haase, much appreciated. I used a few webtools (Cannot install anything: am on a corporate/university computer) all saying: "Does not look like xml" and similar. 

Regarding your dashes comment: you are right, they are not there in the original file, apparantly by copy/paste something went wrong...